# Macro to create a folder and save a file into a sharepoint site

Tags: excel, vba

I have a company sharepoint site onto which I and colleagues need to load daily sheets in a year folder, a month sub-folder and a week ending sub-sub-folder.
I am looking for a way to create the folders as needed automatically without the need for continuously having to create them.
Thanks

I Have tried as below but it comes up with run time error 52.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Dim sFFname As String
Dim sFname As String
Dim sName As String
Dim sFolder As String
Dim sSub As String


sFolder = Range("B69").Value
sSub = Range("B70").Value
sName = Range("B71").Value
sFname = Range("B72").Value
sFFname = Range("B73").Value
    
    
'Define Folder Path for year folder
 sFolderPath = sFolder
      
'Check Specified Folder exists or not
 If Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

'If folder is not available
MkDir (sFolderPath)

'Display Message
MsgBox "Year folder created successfully!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"


Else

    'If folder is available
    MsgBox "Year Folder already exists!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
    
End If
     
   'Variable declaration
    
'Define Folder Path for Month folder
sFolderPath = sSub
    
'Check Specified Folder exists or not
If Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

'If folder is not available
MkDir (sFolderPath)

'Display Message
MsgBox "Month folder created successfully!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"


Else

    'If folder is available
    MsgBox "Month Folder already exists!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
    
End If
     
'Variable declaration
    
'Define Folder Path for Week Ending Folder
sFolderPath = sName
    
'Check Specified Folder exists or not
If Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

'If folder is not available
MkDir (sFolderPath)

'Display Message
MsgBox "Week Ending folder created successfully!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
  
Else

    'If folder is available
    MsgBox "Week Ending folder already exists!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
    
End If


'Set up file to be saved

Dim filename As String ''''filename is the sharepoint site and file name
DirFile = sFFname
If Len(Dir(sFFname)) = 0 Then

'If File exists
MsgBox "File already exists! Open exizting file to edit", vbInformation, "VBAF1"

Else

'Insert commands to Save File below

Folder = Range("B72").Value
Name = Range("H73").Value

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= _
    "Folder & " / " & Name & """
     FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

MsgBox "File saved", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
End If
      
'Display Message
MsgBox "Yipeeee!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"

End Sub
```

The cell references are in the format:
\mycompany.sharepoint.com\sites\mysite\folder\subfolder
with 2 slashes at the start - for some reason not shown on the question

I have tried spaces where the folders have a space in their name and the %20 as well as reversing the \ to / and combinations of the two.

The error starts at the first  If Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

Hovering the mouse over the sFolderPath shows the link from the cell

Is it a formatting issue or a code issue?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: No this is a work PC. It is a "thin client" connected via Citrix to the company server

Comment: Why `"Folder & " / " & Name & """`?  Try `"""" & Folder & "/" & Name & """` Or even add replace space with %20 wrapping above, maybe also other characters to %nn.

Comment: Thanks PatricK, I have sorted the file saving bit on another spreadsheet, the problem I am having is the Folder commands 1st to check if they exist and then if not to create them,

Comment: So pretty much it errors on `Dir(Range("B69").Value,vbDirectory)`? And it's `\\mycompany.sharepoint.com\sites\mysite\folder\subfolder` ?

Comment: That's right, even though hovering over it shows the link. With another spreadsheet I am able to save files to pre-existing folders on the sharepoint using the same link

Comment: With this work PC and same logged on user, if you create a blank workbook, launch VBE, In Immediate Window, does `Dir("\\mycompany.sharepoint.com\sites\mysite\folder\subfolder",vbDirectory)` work? And even parent folders at each level?

Comment: Typing the above directly into the code works and also substituting to a cell in the spreadsheet but it seems that as soon as I go into the third subfolder it throws up an error. Is there a limit to how many sub-sub folders it will work to as this seems to be the wall I am hitting.

Comment: I think what I will do is use a spreadsheet to create all the folders and subfolders on my desktop and then transfer the main folder with everything in it to the SharePoint as, with a bit of effort I can get the basic VBA to work for that.